# не получается использовать в коде "И"

Tags: java

Пытаюсь скомпилировать класс в Java в командной строке. Выдает ошибку: `C:\Users\sadbo\Desktop\Programming\CMD\RandomPhrase>chcp
Active code page: 65001

C:\Users\sadbo\Desktop\Programming\CMD\RandomPhrase>javac RandomPhrase.java
RandomPhrase.java:4: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
String[] wordListOne ={"Потенциальный", "Квантовый", "Резистивный", "Электролитический", "?онный",

Разобрался, что не компилируется из-за буквы "И" в слове Ионный. Что делать если буква нужна?

Comment: Попробуйте скомпилировать в кодировке UTF-8

Comment: Сохраните файл в кодировке utf-8 и добавьте опцию компилятору `-encoding UTF-8`.